# Updating mongo Document object with record deletion changes

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

Currently I have a data structure like this in mongo:

```
{
    _id: value
    colorValues: [
        {
            color: purple  (string)
            stateField: Open  (string)
        }
        {
            color: green  (string)
            stateField: Closed  (string)
        }
    ]
}
```

What I would like to do is update my parent document to include the deletion changes I've kept track of in a separate document. Right now, I am trying this:

```
 private Document generateMongoUpdateDocument(MongoDataSource dataSource, DataChanges dataChanges, String user, Document filter)
{
    DataModel model = dataSource.getModelInstance();
    Document fieldUpdatesDoc = generateFieldUpdatesDoc(dataChanges, filter);
    Document arrayAdds = generateArrayAddsDoc(dataChanges, filter);
    Document arrayDeletes = generateArrayDeletesDoc(dataChanges, filter);

    if (fieldUpdatesDoc != null) Logger.log(DEBUG, "---- fieldUpdates document\n%s", fieldUpdatesDoc.toJson());
    if (arrayAdds != null) Logger.log(DEBUG, "---- arrayAdds document\n%s", arrayAdds.toJson());
    if (arrayDeletes != null) Logger.log(DEBUG, "---- arrayDeletes document\n%s", arrayDeletes.toJson());

    Document updateDocument = new Document();
    if (!fieldUpdatesDoc.isEmpty() || !arrayAdds.isEmpty() || !arrayDeletes.isEmpty())
    {
        fieldUpdatesDoc.append(model.getUpdatedByField().getName(), user);

        updateDocument.append("$set", fieldUpdatesDoc);

        if (!arrayAdds.isEmpty())
        {
            updateDocument.append("$push", arrayAdds);
        }
        if (!arrayDeletes.isEmpty())
        {

            updateDocument.append("$pull", arrayDeletes);
        }

        DataFields updatedAtField = model.getUpdatedAtField();
        if (null != updatedAtField)
        {
            updateDocument.append("$currentDate", new Document(updatedAtField.getName(), true));
        }
    }

    return updateDocument;
}
```

The check "updateDocument.append("$pull", arrayDeletes);" is throwing "Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 2: 'unknown top level operator: $each' on server ******:27012. The full response is {"ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "unknown top level operator: $each", "code" : 2 }"

Can someone guide/tell me how to update my mongo Document properly? Thanks!

EDIT:

```
private Document generateArrayAddsDoc(DataChanges dataChanges, Document filter)
    {
        Document arrayUpdatesDoc = new Document();
        generateArrayDocImpl(arrayUpdatesDoc, null, dataChanges, DataChanges.Type.MODEL_ADD, filter);

        return arrayUpdatesDoc;
    }

private Document generateArrayDeletesDoc(DataChanges dataChanges, Document filter )
    {
        Document arrayDeleteDoc = new Document();
        generateArrayDocImpl(arrayDeleteDoc, null, dataChanges, DataChanges.Type.MODEL_DELETE, filter);

        return arrayDeleteDoc;
    }


private void generateArrayDocImpl(Document arrayUpdateDoc, String parentFieldName, DataChanges dataChanges, DataChanges.Type type, Document filter)
    {
        if (dataChanges.getType() == DataChanges.Type.MODEL_UPDATE)
        {
            for (DataChange dataChange : dataChanges.getDataChanges())
            {
                if (dataChange.getNewValue() instanceof DataChanges)
                {
                    DataChanges arrayChanges = (DataChanges) dataChange.getNewValue();

                    Document arrayDoc = new Document();
                    String dotFieldName = generateDotFieldName(parentFieldName, dataChange.getFieldName());

                    generateArrayDocImpl(arrayDoc, dotFieldName, arrayChanges, type, filter);

                    if (!arrayDoc.isEmpty())
                    {
                        arrayUpdateDoc.append(dotFieldName, arrayDoc);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if (dataChanges.getType() == DataChanges.Type.ARRAY_UPDATE)
        {
            List<Document> updateDocsList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataChange dataChange : dataChanges.getDataChanges())
            {
                Document arrayElementDoc = null;
                DataChanges arrayElementChanges = (DataChanges) dataChange.getNewValue();

                if (arrayElementChanges.getType() == type)
                {
                    arrayElementDoc = generateFieldUpdatesDoc(arrayElementChanges, filter);
                }

                Log.console("ARRAY_ELEMENT_CHANGES == " + arrayElementChanges.toString());

                if (null != arrayElementDoc && !arrayElementDoc.isEmpty())
                {
                    updateDocsList.add(arrayElementDoc);
                }
            }

            if (!updateDocsList.isEmpty())
            {
                arrayUpdateDoc.append("$each", updateDocsList);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does `generateArrayDeletesDoc(dataChanges, filter);` function do ?

Comment: Looks like you are mixing up query forms in `generateArrayAddsDoc(dataChanges, filter);`. Can you post the method snippet?

Comment: I added the methods I am using. I know the DataChanges object structure is a mess (not my design) so i apologize if it's hard to follow.

Comment: The purpose of the generateArrayDocImpl() method is to look for a specific structure of DataChange object where there is a MODEL_DELETE that is nested inside of an ARRAY_UPDATE that is nested inside of a MODEL_UPDATE

Comment: `$each` is only applicable with `$push` and `$addToSet` when adding multiple array values. `$pull` just takes filter. So you may have to update the `generateArrayDocImpl` code to accommodate pull updates.

Comment: @Veeram Okay, if I wanted to $pull on all objects that match the stateField field, what would the filter look like?

Comment: You can try `db.col.update(
    { },
    { $pull: { arrayname: {stateField:statevalue } },
    { multi: true }
)`

Comment: @Veeram with my current implementation, i am unsure how to do it

Comment: I'm not going anywhere with your code flow. Basically, you have to use $each with array updates and $pullAll for array deletes. Try removing `if (!updateDocsList.isEmpty())
            {
                arrayUpdateDoc.append("$each", updateDocsList);
            }` from `generateArrayDocImpl` and update to `if (!arrayAdds.isEmpty())
        {
            updateDocument.append("$push", new Document("$each", arrayAdds));
        }
        if (!arrayDeletes.isEmpty())
        {

            updateDocument.append("$pullAll", arrayDeletes);
        }` in `generateMongoUpdateDocument`